# How to get the current user id (uid) in the form view of Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-view, odoo-domain

I want to add a domain for filtering current user id in the attrs attribute of button in the form view, which is given below :

```
<button name="my_name" attrs="{'invisible': [('my_field', '!=', uid)]}" />
```

Uid is not defined is the error. I tried with user.id, user_id., which also gives the same error. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view model, there is a python eval is execting for attrs attribute, thats why we are getting this error. For overcoming this we have to overide the function named "*transfer_node_to_modifiers*". The code is given below:

```
def transfer_node_to_modifiers(node, modifiers, context=None, in_tree_view=False):
if node.get('attrs'):
    #If you want, add more conditions here
    if ', uid' in  node.get('attrs'):
        user_id = str(context.get('uid', 1))
        user_id = ', ' + user_id
        attrs = node.get('attrs')
        attrs = attrs.replace(', uid', user_id)
        node.set('attrs', attrs)
    modifiers.update(eval(node.get('attrs')))

if node.get('states'):
    if 'invisible' in modifiers and isinstance(modifiers['invisible'], list):
        # TODO combine with AND or OR, use implicit AND for now.
        modifiers['invisible'].append(('state', 'not in', node.get('states').split(',')))
    else:
        modifiers['invisible'] = [('state', 'not in', node.get('states').split(','))]

for a in ('invisible', 'readonly', 'required'):
    if node.get(a):
        v = bool(eval(node.get(a), {'context': context or {}}))
        if in_tree_view and a == 'invisible':
            # Invisible in a tree view has a specific meaning, make it a
            # new key in the modifiers attribute.
            modifiers['tree_invisible'] = v
        elif v or (a not in modifiers or not isinstance(modifiers[a], list)):
            # Don't set the attribute to False if a dynamic value was
            # provided (i.e. a domain from attrs or states).
            modifiers[a] = v
```

Calling the uid is same as question

```
<button name="my_name" attrs="{'invisible': [('my_field', '!=', uid)]}" />
```

I created a patch for this. If anyone needed, please download from [here](https://github.com/manuthalasseril/misc-addons/tree/9.0)

Answer (score 2):

uid is only used within a domain, not within attrs.

Here is a workaround:

1. create a group
2. assign users to group
3. assign group to button.

```
<button name="btn_name" type="object" string="string" groups="module.group_name"/>
```

Comment: Nice solution. But in my case I have a requirement of getting uid on form view. Because I want to hide the button in between users, even if they belong to same group.

Comment: then you should create another group for those users

Answer (score 2):

try this way

1. create a Boolean field in ResUsers.
2. create a boolean type compute field in class of your form.

   mark compute field True if Boolean field in ResUsers is True.
   if self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid).show_button:
     
     self.computefield = True
3. use compute field in attrs on button

Comment: Thank you for your attention and time. I solved it and I updated it in the answer section.